# Type 'American' does not conform to protocol 'Food'

Tags: swift, struct

have been fighting the code for some time now, and can't resolve the issue of: `Type 'American' does not conform to protocol 'Food'`

```
protocol Food {
    var type: String { get }
    var ingredient1: String { get }
    var price: Int { get set}
    func showHistory() 
    mutating func transfer()

    init(type: String)
    init(ingredient1: String)
}

struct American: Food {
    let type: String 
    let ingredient1: String
    var price: Int = 125

    init(type: String, ingredient1: String) {
        self.type = type
        self.ingredient1 = ingredient1
    }

    func showHistory() {    
        print("American history")
    }

    mutating func transfer() {   
        print("transfering burgers")
    }
}
```

Comment: The protocol requires both `init(type: String)` and `init(ingredient1: String)`, which `American` clearly doesn't have - it has `init(type: String, ingredient1: String)`, which requires both parameters, while the protocol conforming type needs to support either on their own

Comment: ok  many thanks. I've ammended following your help... quick followup if I may.
i am combining the strcut with a class (therefore protocol), when I write the following:

let USA = American(type: "Burger", ingredient1: "Pepper")

Comment: I am met with the following error    Extra argument 'ingredient1' in call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt you intended to separate your inits into two separate calls which is causing your error. You could solve this by implementing two separate inits as well but then you'd have to initialize both properties in separate inits which will give you an error

```
  protocol Food {
    var type: String { get }
    var ingredient1: String { get }
    var price: Int { get set}
    func showHistory() 
    mutating func transfer()

    
    init(type: String, ingredient1: String)
}

struct American: Food {
    let type: String 
    let ingredient1: String
    var price: Int = 125

    init(type: String, ingredient1: String) {
        self.type = type
        self.ingredient1 = ingredient1
    }

    func showHistory() {    
        print("American history")
    }

    mutating func transfer() {   
        print("transfering burgers")
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks  really appreicate the help, and clarity

Comment: @PaulT, if this answer helped you solve your problem then you should mark it as accepted